# How debug, wrong output?

Tags: java, debugging

After testing my code, I found a bug which I don't know how to fix.
When I start this code with String parameter = "asd fgh", then I see this output "hgf" instead of "hgf dsa".

```
public String reverseWords(String input) {
    String oneOrMoreSpaces = "\\s+";
    String[] words = input.split(oneOrMoreSpaces);
    String completeAnagram = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        char[] symbol = words[i].toCharArray();
        char newSymbolSequence;
        int j = symbol.length - 1, k = 0;

        while (k < j) {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(symbol[k]))
                k++;
            else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(symbol[j]))
                j--;
            else {
                newSymbolSequence = symbol[k];
                symbol[k] = symbol[j];
                symbol[j] = newSymbolSequence;
                k++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        completeAnagram = new String(symbol);
    }
    return completeAnagram;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you split the input , if it contains spaces by

```
String[] words = input.split(oneOrMoreSpaces);
```

then you cycle through them with a `for` loop .

each word words is stored in `char[] symbol = words[i].toCharArray();`

the problem is `completeAnagram = new String(symbol);`

when you run the loop out of every words , it stores only the recent ran one ; hence , when you run the last loop , it holds only the last word which is analyzed .